# Spring-WS endpoints document literal wrapping/unwrapping

Tags: java, spring, soap, wsdl, spring-ws

I am integrating with a system that expects us to consume WS-I 1.1 document/literal wrapped messages.  We have a working solution but it appears like there could be a simpler way to deal with payload wrapping/unwrapping.

I have an endpoint that as follows:

```
@Endpoint
public class FooEndpoint
{

  @Autowired
  private FooService FooService;

  @PayloadRoot(localPart = "Foo", namespace = "http://foo/service")
  @ResponsePayload
  public JAXBElement<FooAcknowledgementType> Foo(
        @RequestPayload JAXBElement<FooRequestType> requestElement)
  {
    FooRequestType request = requestElement.getValue();
    FooAcknowledgementType response = FooService.Foo(request);

    // TODO: Find a better solution with the wrapped response
    return new JAXBElement<FooAcknowledgementType>(new QName(
          "http://foo/service", "FooAcknowledgement"),
          FooAcknowledgementType.class, null, response);
  }
}
```

and a WSDL which defines the contract is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:tns="http://foo/service" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns1="http://foo/schema"
  name="Foo" targetNamespace="http://foo/service">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:s="http://foo/schema" targetNamespace="http://foo/service">
      <xsd:import namespace="http://foo/schema" schemaLocation="foo_types.xsd" />
      <xsd:element name="Foo" type="s:FooRequestType" />
      <xsd:element name="FooAcknowledgement" type="s:FooAcknowledgementType" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="FooRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:Foo" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="FooAcknowledgement">
    <wsdl:part name="parameter" element="tns:FooAcknowledgement" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="FooPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="Foo">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:FooRequest" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:FooAcknowledgement" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="FooBinding" type="tns:FooPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Foo">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://foo/serviceFoo" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Foo">
    <wsdl:documentation>Foo web service</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:port name="FooService" binding="tns:FooBinding">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/foo/services/Foo" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I've generated jaxb objects from the foo_types.xsd schema as referenced in the endpoint class above.

The issue is that when we receive soap messages in document/literal wrapped style the soap body payload would look like

```
<x:Foo>
  <!-- elements from s:FooRequestType -->
</x:Foo>
```

and we are expected to respond with a soap body payload like

```
<x:FooAcknowledgement>
  <!-- elements from s:FooAcknowledgementType -->
</x:FooAcknowledgement>
```

Is there anyway that the Spring-WS can handle this out of the box?  We can consume and produce compliant messages with the code as it is but it seems like this might not be the right way to go about it as this style is not referenced in the spring docs at http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html#tutorial.xsd

Comment: No not really. You could use the `ObjectFactory` to make it a little cleaner. The problem is your JAXB objects aren't `@XmlRootElement`s and as such cannot be used directly and have to be wrapped. You could change the xsd but that would mean you need to have control over the xsd if you don't there isn't much you could do.

Comment: I have used a JAXB binding file to add those annotations to the JAXB objects, so that isn't the cause.

Comment: It isn't only a fact of those annotations being available, just slapping those annotations on there without having the correct xsd structure won't help.

Comment: The XSD is a stable interface and a number of other implementors are using it so don't think its structure is incorrect.  I'm thinking that Spring-WS with JAXB doesnt seem to play long with literal wrapped style.

Comment: If JAXB cannot determine the root elements just adding `@XmlRootElement` won't help. JAXB needs to be able to determine them based on the XSD. This has nothing to do with Spring WS but is a JAXB problem which doesn't know how to marshal the objects, hence they need to be wrapped. You could try using a `Jaxb2Marshaller` and set the `supportJaxbElementClass` to true and try again with your classes (non wrapped).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for us was to add the namespace and element name to the @XmlRootElement annotation via our jaxb bindings.xml, E.g.

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='fooType']">
  <annox:annotate target="class">
    <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" name="FooAcknowledgement" namespace="http://foo/service"/>
  </annox:annotate>
</jaxb:bindings>
```